# How to achieve multi select dropdown checkbox list in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Hi good evening everyone, I am making  a web based application ‘Workshop Management’ using C#, ASP.Net and SQL Server and have got stuck at this issue

I have a jobcard page which contains various fields like `jobcard no,
datein, dateout etc` which can be accomplished with a simple `textbox` control but there are three more fields namely `faultsFound, repairCarriedOut, sparesRequired` where I want them to be displayed as `dropdown` checkbox list so that i can select multiple values at once and then store those values in database. 
And this spares required will be listed against each jobcard number and displayed to the storekeeper once he login.

The storekeeper will then provide the available spares and place a demand for the spares which are not available in store.

The number of items in each of the above three fields `(faultsFound, repairCarriedOut, sparesRequired)` varies between 20 to 30 items ex: `sparesRequired` contains items like : head light, rare view mirror, coolant etc
There is no `dropdown` checkbox list control available for `webforms`. Please guide me on this how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Technical Details :

IDE : Visual Studio 2012.

Programming Language : C#, ASP.Net

Backend DB : SQL Server 2016

Webforms

[Image of webform requiring dropdown checkbox list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pLyI.png)

Comment: webforms? or mvc? also show us what you have done so far

Comment: I am using webforms to develop the application, so far I have started to do this part of the project attached the screenshot for the same

Comment: Hi Laxman,  please check this : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown

Comment: I think it is interesting that you think asp.net should have anything to do with solving this problem when it is HTML, CSS and Javascript that really are what will allow you to solve this easily.

Comment: Thanks Anura was able to resolve the issue, also found another link to implement dropdown checkbox list using jquery http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Dropdownlist-with-checkboxes-in-asp-net